# Button that forces all embedded youtube videos on a page to play simultaneously, be muted, and loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a button that a user can click that will force all embedded youtube videos on a page to begin playing simultaneously, be muted, and loop.

This is the page I am trying to implement the button on -
[www.missingnewyork.com/last-seen](http://www.missingnewyork.com/last-seen)

To embed each video I am using the following code which now includes ?enablejsapi=1 after each url -

```
    <div id="horizontalcontainer">
        <div id="scrolling-wrapper-video">
            <div class="videocard1">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1i3x82LoQ1M?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UrJmZ57EHwg?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kgcB41C9i94?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qB5ityfsboU?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RM0nrCooQic?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>               
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wqobN25apx4?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4niCIE9xca4?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MGWwy_zt6KU?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JheP24KKaYo?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8LuzXamIyjE?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_jv9TQlrru8?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0TBYVXG1css?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KqQqxC7aGhw?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VUzoFhqYbo8?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ypQjjIoO1Mc?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>                  
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lzY70qA2Tr4?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-UprcCZIX0?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>               
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DH-TFgizhxw?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bme8Aa_Z1X0?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="videocard">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kw3SAx4Hsd8?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
            <div class="videocardlast">
                <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/86DRzKe69i8?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried using the following function that was provided in the answer on this post -

```
function playAllVideos() {
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src^="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"]');
    videos.forEach(function(video) {
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"mute","args":""}', '*');
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"setLoop","args":"1"}', '*');
    });
}
```

And here is the button I am using -

```
<button id="play-all" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;">PLAY ALL</button>
```

and here is what I have to make the button have a relationship with the function -

```
var playAllButton = document.getElementById('play-all');

playAllButton.addEventListener('click', playAllVideos);
```

Unfortunately when I click the button, nothing happens. I am thinking there is probably something wrong with this last chunk of code... does anyone see where I am going wrong?

And to clarify, I only want the videos to autoplay / loop / be muted, IF, the user clicks on the PLAY ALL button. If the user doesn't click on the PLAY ALL button, I need the page to act exactly as it currently does.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it really  ^ and not * after src?   var videos = ('iframe[src  ^ ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"]');

Comment: I am not quite sure. That is how chatgpt had thought it should be formatted.

Comment: ChatGPT isn't really a programmer. From what you posted, there's no relationship between that function and the code on the page. The function has to be bound as an event handler to the button.

Comment: @JohnSmith  "If we were to use the ^ selector instead, it would only match iframe elements whose src attribute starts with the exact string "youtube.com/embed/". This would not match any iframe element whose src attribute contains additional parameters after the "youtube.com/embed/" part of the URL." So it wont get anything after "embed/"

Comment: @Pointy I have added what I believe is an event handler to create a relationship between the button and the function, but I am still struggling to get it to work. I have updated my post with the new code

Comment: I posted an answer with two different solutions, the first one is more practical. take a look at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two solutions for the problem;

**First Solution**, You should add `?enablejsapi=1` to the url and `allow="autoplay"` for the iframe tag (you're already allowing "autoplay" in the iframe), your function should work then.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-UprcCZIX0?enablejsapi=1" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```
function playAllVideos() {
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src^="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"]');
    videos.forEach(function(video) {
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"mute","args":""}', '*');
        video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"setLoop","args":"1"}', '*');
    });
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512309/youtube-iframe-not-responding-to-postmessage-commands)

**Second solution**, *(isn't the best one)* is by modifying the iframes sources to include `?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1` options in their srcs. It doesn't give the most smooth experience for playing all videos at once as it takes a second loading all the videos due to changing the source, but it works fine. I tried it on the website you [linked here](https://www.missingnewyork.com/last-seen).

If you want to stop all videos, just remove the options from the souce.

```
function playAllVideos() {
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src^="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"]');

    videos.forEach(function(video) {
        video.src = video.src + "?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1";
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am trying to get the first solution to work with my code, but I can't get it to work yet. I have added the '?enablejsapi=1' to the end of each url and I have copied the function into the script. I'm thinking there is something wrong with my actual button. I have updated my post with the new code I am using from your answer. Do you see where I am still going wrong?

Comment: @JohnSmith You're welcome! Where do you include your `script` tag, it's better to include it under the body at the bottom of the html so that the window is loaded. Another alternative use `window.onload = function(){ \\ your script code}` at your script and add all your script inside the onload function to make sure the dom is loaded. Try `console.log(window)` or `console.log(document)` at the start of your script, if they are `undefined` because the dom isn't loaded yet, so no events are added. If you can share your button code in a jsfiddle or as executable code, it'll be better.

Comment: Moving the script below the body worked perfectly!! You are a life saver. Super appreciate you. Thank you again so much.

Comment: @JohnSmith You're welcome, Mr. Magician, Good luck with your coding!